# {NSLocalizedDescription=Garbage after JSON}

Tags: objective-c, json, garbage

I'm getting this error msg from the JSON result sent by the Twitter search API.

Any ideas on what it means & how to avoid it? Its kind of a random error, since it does not always appear.

-JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=10 \"Garbage after JSON\" UserInfo=0x5c49900 {NSLocalizedDescription=Garbage after JSON}"

Thanks

Comment: I Post an answer here(Using JSONKit instead):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174953/jsonvalue-failed-error-trace-isgarbage-after-json/12052446#12052446

Answer (score 0):

Commenting this code solves the problem (SBJsonParser.m):

// We found some valid JSON. But did it also contain something else?
    /*if (![self scanIsAtEnd]) {
        [self addErrorWithCode:ETRAILGARBAGE description:@"Garbage after JSON"];
        return nil;
    }*/