# -JSONValue Failed error trace is:Garbage after JSON

Tags: iphone, json

I am using Json Parsing with autosuggestion

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
autoCompleteTable.hidden = NO;

NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
substring = [substring stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
if(substring.length>=3)
{
    [self getDescriptionData];

[self searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:substring];

}
else {
    [placesArray removeAllObjects];
    [autoCompleteTable reloadData];
}

return YES;
}
```

JSON value is retrieved in getDescription method. but when it is called second tine i am getting error:
 -JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=10 \"Garbage after JSON\" UserInfo=0x4b60160 {NSLocalizedDescription=Garbage after JSON}"
)

Comment: when i enter 3 characters in the textfield then it call the JSON Parser & works fine but when i enter the next character in the text field it gives error:Garbage after JSON.

Answer (score 0):

i met the same thing.
After googling and stackflowing, i found nothing.

so i decide to use  JSONKit instead:
(github: https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit)

```
    // sbjson
    // NSString *jsonStr = [NSString stringWithCString:[receivedData bytes]
    //                                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    // NSArray *returnArr = [jsonStr JSONValue];


    // jsonkit
    JSONDecoder *decoder = [JSONDecoder decoder];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *returnArr = [decoder objectWithData:receivedData error:&error];
```

Finally, this works.